# Paste Function Not working for first time jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$(".editableContent").bind('paste', function() {
var value = $(this).text();
var string = value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
$(this).text(string);
});
});
</script>
```

Paste Function Does not work for first time but second time it works , why?

Comment: Could you please reproduce that in a js-fiddle?

Comment: The paste handler fires the first time: http://jsfiddle.net/zyL2Q/. What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4ctVx/1/) this is working fiddle

Comment: man just select some images and paste in the contenteditable div in fiddle! You will see rendered images in div for first time but not the second time!

Comment: now the fiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/4ctVx/4/

Comment: How do you "select" images? Do you want me to paste the markup for an image into the div?

Comment: if you are going to create a fiddle to show jQuery not working... at least include jQuery as framework!

Comment: The "paste" event occurs *before* the to-be-inserted text is pasted into the text field. It just looks like it works the second time, but try pasting two different snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to remove markup from your editable div. Just use this:

```
$(".editableContent").on('paste', function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).find('*').remove();
        $(self).append('<br />')
    }, 0);
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/4jSNN/1/

Comment: nah man i was just removing the HTML tag from the value of the div content pasted!